# Extension of an array with generic elements

Tags: swift, generics

The following structure compiles without errors:

```
struct AIEvaluation<T> : CustomDebugStringConvertible where T: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var param: T
    var value: Double

    var debugDescription: String {
        return param.debugDescription + ": " + String(format: "%.2f", value)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write an extension for an array `[AIEvalution<T>]` where T is still a generic type?

Tried the following:

```
extension Array where Element == AIEvaluation  {...}
extension Array where Element == AIEvaluation<T>  {...}
extension Array where Element == AIEvaluation<T> where T:CustomDebugStringConvertible  {...}
extension <T:CustomDebugStringConvertible> Array where Element == AIEvaluation<T>  {...}
```

and others. Tried also redefining `AIEvaluation` as a class. Any time I get a (different) compilation error.

Comment: Some suggestions here: https://forums.swift.org/t/extension-on-array-where-element-is-generic-type/10225/4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create a generic function in the `Array` extension:

```
extension Array {
    func foo<T>() where Element == AIEvaluation<T> {
        ...
    }
}
```