# Extension to Array with generic elements with custom initializer

Tags: swift, generics

### Disclaimer

Please note this is only a simplified example. Actual problem is a bit more complex so I need actual Array extension rather than other solution.
I know that

```swift
let mapped: [MyGeneric<Int>] = items.map { .init(someVariable: $0) }
```

will work, but I'm looking for a way to write generic array extension not fix this simplified code

### Problem

I'm trying to write a generic extension to an array/collection as below:

```swift
struct MyGeneric<T: Hashable> {
    let someVariable: T
}
```

### Expected output

Code below is not working because I'm missing Array extension, but ideally my output would be something like this:

```swift
let items: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let mapped: [MyGeneric<Int>] = .init(items)
```

So what I need is:

```swift
extension [MyGeneric<Hashable>] {
    init(someArray: [some Hashable]) {
        self = someArray.map { MyGeneric(someVariable: $0)}
    }
}
```

but of course this is not compiling because generic parameter from extension is not passed to init generic parameter. How can I pass the type from extension to functions in that. Can I use somehow `Element.Type` in this one and extract Generic type from there? Or maybe there is an `extension Array where ...` syntax that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62253008/1187415, the same approach should work for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the answer provided by @MartinR I came up with the following solution

```
extension Array {
    init<T>(_ array: [T]) where Element == MyGeneric<T> {
        self.init(array.map(MyGeneric.init))
    }
}
```

Comment: The constraint on T is not needed, apparently the compiler infers it from the definition of MyGeneric. So `init<T>(_ array: [T]) where Element == MyGeneric<T>` is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I didn't even consider that.